# Changes in Google API's Places( I can't use google anymore)

Tags: android, api, google-places-api

there. I used google place api web service for my android app. But now i can't. I guess something changed at google server.

When I sent url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=new+york&sensor=true&key=", I got response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <name>New York</name>
        <type>locality</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>New York, NY, USA</formatted_address>
        <geometry>
            <location>
                <lat>40.7127837</lat>
                <lng>-74.0059413</lng>
            </location>
            <viewport>
                <southwest>
                    <lat>40.4913699</lat>
                    <lng>-74.2590899</lng>
                </southwest>
                <northeast>
                    <lat>40.9152556</lat>
                    <lng>-73.7002721</lng>
                </northeast>
            </viewport>
        </geometry>
        <icon>https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png</icon>
        <reference>CnRuAAAAnEO6PjZXaN0fGelpsmrS9-TzHP2zi3RdI17Lzbsnx8E_8zGwHIzJx9sVF5O7CKhVd95-8D-Vd39UaBO4pIT6Yu7aFJfFUkZxZWbqTbY_S2gm8zvczDXBMIIaBCn5sIJz9OWHpm4Bk92yydz4iba1uBIQBq5OGWcAag8DwGRm00rWJRoUcAme3KG3GQJJr-dywFWtvo5LVJs</reference>
        <id>7eae6a016a9c6f58e2044573fb8f14227b6e1f96</id>
        <place_id>ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g</place_id>
    </result>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

But now I got response like this:

```
��������������mS]W�0}�Wp�,M�{"�Zu-��۵�p"
-��HB?���Z�*O�wf�e&|�[gچ"e�E�hF���|qјNnu�q��AFb:����#*8�
�4,$���]GET��T'
�dM���f�xŠ�/��I��=5<�)6U��@5���#2�+qT=�f��t���{RU��lMe����+S�z���Dl�r=�ŠH�t�jBh�a��"j   �EoR������-|��|�t|�����>����C��se��䛮o�ȶ�tͦ!r��E������p��Rr��5ᢹ�n9��1[WD�fT��^�FDx
�Qi���k4y��5[�4���.��Q�R������X�˱yU>��`��Ĝg�6l�t1u�S�B�G�{o�IX�,�ޞV[V��Z��Љ����(�tt�ļ�]}��i�I�o�$zH�3���vK�n���=h��H4��:7��M����;a�M��{7×pǦ�!j�l�{JG��.���]�^��|�Wo��P�@�!~�$�G�,�5�/1,������N%W5�&�@{� ��E��V��f۴�d���<�Yꭁ�ǆOO�/gs�g�����
```

Why I got the above response? Is it possible to fix it?

If not, should I use google places api for android? I can't find api at google places api that is similar to google places api web service. What is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing url to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml` @user1952115

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use the API direct no api web, like Google Maps API V2 Android.

You have examples to follow steps. [HERE](https://developers.google.com/places/android/?hl=es)